# show struts2 max file size error

Tags: struts2

while uploading the max file size using struts2 i am getting "File too large:" in the console.How to Show this error message on Jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example :
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/

[image]

Comment: What's not worked? Have you tried run and explore the example http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Struts2-File-Upload-Example.zip ?